# How to run JavaScript code with Crawljax

Tags: web-crawler

I want to make my web site crawlable by Google's search indexer.

I'm using crawljax to automate an AJAX call and to give a snapshot of "static pages" for my website's dynamic pages.

The problem is that I haven't found a way to simulate running JavaScript code like firing triggers or calling a certain function on my site.

How can that be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

Look at writing Crawljax plugins [here](https://github.com/crawljax/crawljax/wiki/Writing-a-plugin)

To run javascript, you would call the executeJavaScript() function in [EmbeddedBrowser](http://crawljax.com/apidocs/com/crawljax/browser/EmbeddedBrowser.html#executeJavaScript%28java.lang.String%29) class